# How to use Timer with a function that returns a dataframe?

Tags: python, google-analytics-api

I want to query an API every *n* minutes and parse the response into a dataframe. However, I am getting a **TypeError** when trying to do so:

> TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable

I have tried:

- Running a function that returns a get request
- Running a function that returns the above into a pandas dataframe

In #1, I get "'dict' object is not callable".
 In #2, I get "'DataFrame not callable'" error (as shown above).
  Both work fine if I instead print the result of the functions **BUT** I need to do computations on the result and hence require a dataframe response to be returned.

It seems like I am missing something obvious. Can anyone please elucidate?

Reference:

```
from threading import Timer, Thread

def run_alert(time):
t = Timer(time, print_query_results(*args))
t.start()
```

EDIT #1:

The DataFrame object is response from the API formatted into a 10x3 table:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

    medium    source    pageviews
0   DIRECT    (not set) xxx
1   ORGANIC   google    xxx
2   ORGANIC   yahoo     xxx
4   ORGANIC   bing      xxx
*     *       *          *
```

EDIT #2:

```
def print_query_results(ids, metrics, dimensions, filters, sort):   

#get results from request
results = run_query(ids, metrics, dimensions, filters, sort)

#convert json into dataframe
cols = json_normalize(results['columnHeaders'])['name']
rows = json_normalize(results, 'rows')

cols_names = []

for name in cols:
    cols_names.append(name.split(":")[1])

df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
df.columns = [cols_names]
df.rename(columns = {'pageviews':'pageviews'+" "+strftime('%I:%M %p')}, inplace=True)

df = df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)

return df
```

Comment: can you share more details about the 'DataFrame' object?

Comment: Timer is trying to call `print_query_results(*args)`, which isn't a function when evaluated - it's whatever the `return` statement in `print_query_results` is. Pass it a `lambda: print_query_results(*args)` instead maybe?

Comment: I have added imports and example df output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I said in my comments (and there should really be appropriate tags and even `import` statements to show exactly what Timer/DataFrame are), your threading.Timer object wants something callable - so that when the time is elapsed, it can spin up a thread with that chunk of computation.

When you pass `Timer` `print_query_results(*args)`, the function `print_query_results` is evaluated by the interpreter before being passed to the `Timer`, so you get a `dict` or a `DataFrame` or whatever the function is returning - not a function. One way to work around this would be

```
t = Timer(time, lambda: print_query_results(*args))
```

We can't see enough of your program to make recommendations beyond this sort of workaround, but in these type mismatch situations there's usually an underlying conceptual problem which merits some refactoring.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried lambda, but it doesn't seem to be returning the expected output. Do you think it could be because I am running an iterative function in ipython notebook?

Comment: I think you should be more specific - saying it isn't returning what you expected is too vague. What did you expect and why? What did you get instead?

Comment: Sorry, I will elaborate. It's expected output is the 10x3 dataframe as shown in the question, but it's not returning anything. Thoughts?

Comment: Can you post the body of the function

Comment: I think there's something wrong with your indentation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92014/discussion-between-a-p-and-silky-axis).